# SQL - Negative Hours Cumulative Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to keep a track of negative only balances. If the results is positive, then it should only "0". I only want to keep a track of negative hours.

The SQL should add the difference from the next line to the previous if it's negative

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    s.id, s.differencefromzero AS [Negative Only Hours], 
    s.difference, answer = 0
FROM 
    Staff_Tracked_Hours s
WHERE
    s.personID = '000033485'

ORDER BY
    s.ID ASC
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Why doesn't `answer` start with 23.5?  What if the row after the "1" were "2"?

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output data

Comment: As i mentioned, I dont want any positive results in the "answer" column. It its positive then it should be 0.  If the row after the 1 was 2 instead of 9.5, then it should be -1 as the answer as -3 + 2 would be -1.

Comment: How are you deciding which positive value to add and which one not? the row after 1 is already positive. why are you not adding 9.5 to -3?

Comment: It should add them all but if the result goes postive, then the answer column should be 0 only. It should never go positive. The answer column should always be 0 or negative.

Comment: How do you sort your data?

Comment: by ID. It should sort by ID ASC - Ill add it in the code above

Comment: I'll try working on my cte in a couple hours, and repost when I have it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of this problem is recursive. I first added a new `row_number()` column to your original table and then I use a recursive `CTE` to get the result:

```
declare @t table (id int, NegativeOnlyHours int, [difference] float); -- original table
insert into @t values(437, 0, 23.5), (442, -4, -4), (447, 0, 1), (452, 0, 9.5);

-- SOLUTION:
with cte
as
(
select 1 as Num, id, NegativeOnlyHours, [difference], CASE when [difference]>0 then 0 else [difference] END as answer  
    from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as num, id, NegativeOnlyHours, [difference] from @t) t1 where num = 1
union all
(select cte.Num + 1, t.id, t.NegativeOnlyHours, t.[difference], 
    CASE
        WHEN answer + t.[difference] > 0 THEN 0
        ELSE answer + t.[difference]
    END as answer 
 from cte 
join (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as num, id, NegativeOnlyHours, [difference] from @t) t 
on t.NUM = cte.Num + 1)
)
select id, NegativeOnlyHours, [difference], answer from cte;
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Is there a way to do this without having to create multiple tables for it?  Can it be done just using the table that already exists?

Comment: @DavidHayward Yes. just need to use a sub-query instead. I edited my post with the sub-query.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I tried the below and it doesnt seem to work if the first difference value is more than 0 as the answer always come back as 0 for the first line.

Comment: @DavidHayward You are right. I fixed it. Check it out.

Comment: @DavidHayward David, can you plz accept this solution if it worked for you? and If it wasn't helpful, let us know.